# Eclipse workspace error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, websphere, ibm-rad

First time posting with SOF. We are trying to migrate IBM RAD based web project to Eclipse STS. I am able to get rid of most of the errors after checking out the code but the bindings file is throwing the exception:

```
Resource reference with name 'jdbc/xyz' not found
```

Web.xml version is 2.5. Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Creating and configuring resource references for Web 2.5 - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jee5.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftcreateconfigresref.html . Hope it makes sense to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This tells you, that you dont have resource refernce with the name jdbc/xyz. You need to either define one in web.xml, or check, if somewhere in the code you are using annotation @Resource. It should have name jdbc/xyz, like this:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/xyz")
DataSource ds;
```